# jQuery automatic and manual slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

The webpage requires a slideshow that will run automatically, but you can jump to the next or previous slide if needed by pressing a button. I provide my code. How can I add an auto slideshow and optimize this code variation as much as possible?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

changeSlide('next');

$('#sliderToLeft').on('click', function() {
    changeSlide('previous');
});

$('#sliderToRight').on('click', function() {
    changeSlide('next');
});

function changeSlide(direction) {
    var currentSlide = $('.active');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slide');
    var previousSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    if (direction == 'next') {
        if (nextSlide.length) {
            nextSlide.addClass('active');
            nextSlide.children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            nextSlide.children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            nextSlide.children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            nextSlide.children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        } else {
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().addClass('active');
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        }
    } else {
        if (previousSlide.length) {
            previousSlide.addClass('active');
            previousSlide.children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            previousSlide.children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            previousSlide.children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            previousSlide.children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        } else {
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().addClass('active');
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        }
    }

    currentSlide.removeClass('active');
    currentSlide.children('h1').slideUp();
    currentSlide.children('h2').slideUp();
    currentSlide.children('h3').slideUp();
    currentSlide.children('button').slideUp();

}});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
setInterval(function() { 
 changeSlide('next');
},  3000);
```

like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

setInterval(function() { 
 changeSlide('next');
},  3000);


$('#sliderToLeft').on('click', function() {
    changeSlide('previous');
});

$('#sliderToRight').on('click', function() {
    changeSlide('next');
});

function changeSlide(direction) {
    var currentSlide = $('.active');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slide');
    var previousSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    if (direction == 'next') {
        if (nextSlide.length) {
            nextSlide.addClass('active');
            nextSlide.children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            nextSlide.children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            nextSlide.children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            nextSlide.children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        } else {
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().addClass('active');
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').first().children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        }
    } else {
        if (previousSlide.length) {
            previousSlide.addClass('active');
            previousSlide.children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            previousSlide.children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            previousSlide.children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            previousSlide.children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        } else {
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().addClass('active');
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('h1').delay(1000).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('h2').delay(1200).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('h3').delay(1900).slideDown(800);
            $('#slidesArea > .slide').last().children('button').delay(2800).slideDown(800);
        }
    }

    currentSlide.removeClass('active');
    currentSlide.children('h1').slideUp();
    currentSlide.children('h2').slideUp();
    currentSlide.children('h3').slideUp();
    currentSlide.children('button').slideUp();

}});
```

Comment: An additional solution is needed. Let's say 2 seconds have passed. I press the button next. Then the slide is shown to me for only 1 second and automatically turns on the next. How can I fix this?